# server-client chat using python with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I'm trying to setup a command prompt chat between two hosts. To enable typing and printing simultaneously, I'm using `threading`. One PC is set up as server with the following code:

```
def recvfun():
    for i in range(5):
        print c.recv(1024)
    return

def sendfun():
    for i in range(5):
        c.send(raw_input())
    return

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print 'Got connection from', addr

try:
    Thread(target = recvfun, args = []).start()
    Thread(target = sendfun, args = []).start()
except Exception,errtxt:
    print errtxt

c.close()                   # Close the connection
```

And the other PC is set up with the following similar code:

```
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
host = "192.168.1.111"
s.connect((host, port))

try:
    Thread(target = recvfun, args = []).start()
    Thread(target = sendfun, args = []).start()
except Exception,errtxt:
    print errtxt

s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

At the moment I'm running both client and server on same machine, with two command prompts. But whenever I try to send or receive texts, I'm getting following error logs on server command prompt:

```
Got connection from ('192.168.1.111', 25789)
hi
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\programs\server.py", line 12, in sendfun
    c.send(raw_input())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Could any of you please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how it can be resolved.

Thank you for reading!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads start and wait for you to type in code, while at the same time the main programs continue running and immediately close the socket or connection, making it unusable for sending data and causing the error. You have to wait for the threads to finish before closing anything. You can demonstrate this just by removing the `close` calls.

Comment: Thank you!! Now it's working. Could you let me know how I can get the program to wait for threads to finish and then close it?